# Is there a better Ruby or Rails idiom for checking for the presence of values in a nested hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

If the value:

```
myhash['first_key']['second_key']
```

exists, then I need to get it. But `'second_key'` may not be present at all in `my_hash`, and I don't want that line to throw an exception if it is not.

Right now I am wrapping the whole thing in an ugly conditional like so:

```
if myhash['first_key'].present? and myhash['first_key']['second_key'].present?
  ...
end
```

I'm sure there must be something simpler.

Comment: Don't use `and` keyword for conditions. Use `&&`

Comment: Err, the problem is that `second_key` **isn't** present in `my_hash`. It's a key in a second hash, completely unrelated to `my_hash` You're nesting two completely different Hash objects.

Comment: By "present" do you mean not `nil` or not blank or `nil`? For example, if it exists, but it's `' '` or even `''` is that considered "present" or no?

Comment: You might want to use the `.try(:something)` method: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Comment: An aside: @SergioTulentsev, I've seen it stated before, but why is `&&` preferred over `and` for conditions?

Comment: @mbratch: they have different precedence.

Comment: You can just use `||`; `if (myhash['first_key'] || {})['second_key']`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use `try`:

```
hsh.try(:[], 'first_key').try(:[], 'second_key')
```

FYI: if you're doing a lot of these checks, you might want to refactor your code to avoid these situations.

Comment: Is this a rails method? That `#try` ?

Comment: Yep, Rails method. OP tagged the question as RoR.

Comment: No issue, I don't know ROR.. he he :)

Comment: I don't know how I would refactor this, other than to move it.

Comment: If you provide some more context I could probably help out.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, write a wrapper:

```rb
h = {
  first_key: {
    second_key: 'test'
  }
}

class Hash
  def fetch_path(*parts)
    parts.reduce(self) do |memo, key|
      memo[key] if memo
    end
  end
end

h.fetch_path(:first_key, :second_key) # => "test"
h.fetch_path(:first_key, :third_key) # => nil
h.fetch_path(:first_key, :third_key, :fourth_key) # => nil
h.fetch_path(:foo, :third_key) # => nil
```

Comment: how is this? `hsh = {a: {c: 1}}
[:a,:d].inject(hsh,:[]) # => nil`

Comment: @babai: that won't handle query like `:a, :d, :e`

Answer (score 4):

Try this neat and clean solution. Hash default values:

```
h = Hash.new( {} ) # sets a hash as default value
```

Now do what you like:

```
h[:some_key] # => {}
h[:non_existent_key][:yet_another_non_existent_key] # => nil
```

Nice?

Say you have an existing hash, which is already populated:

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

So you just set its default to return a new hash:

```
h.default = {}
```

And there you go again:

```
h[:d] # => {}
h[:d][:e] # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd point you to the excellent [Hashie::Mash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash)

An example:

```
mash = Hashie::Mash.new

# Note: You used to be able to do : `mash.hello.world` and that would return `nil`
# However it seems that behavior has changed and now you need to use a `!` :

mash.hello!.world # => nil  # Note use of `!`


mash.hello!.world = 'Nice'  # Multi-level assignment!


mash.hello.world # => "Nice"
# or
mash.hello!.world # => "Nice"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up some default values before processing the hash. Something like:

```
myhash[:first_key] ||= {}

if myhash[:first_key][:second_key]
  # do work
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a method for this?

```
class Hash
  def has_second_key?(k1,k2)
    self[k1] ? self[k1][k2] : nil
  end
end
new_hash = {}
new_hash["a"] = "b"
new_hash["c"] = {"d"=>"e","f"=>"g"}
new_hash[:p] = {q:"r"}
new_hash.has_second_key?("r","p")
  # =>nil
new_hash.has_second_key?("c","f")
  # =>"g"
new_hash.hash_second_key?(:p,:q)
  # =>"r"
```

To modify your code, it would be:

```
if myhash.has_second_key?('first-key','second-key') 
  ...
end
```

This method will return `nil`, which is Falsey in Ruby, or will return the value of the second key which is Truthy in Ruby.

Obviously you do not have to modify the Hash class if you don't want to. You could have the method except the hash as an argument too. `has_second_key?(hash,k1,k2)`. Then call it as:

```
has_second_key?(myhash,'first-key','second-key')
```